# Require application_name for incoming connections

Tags: postgresql, connection, database-connection, postgresql-11

I am passing the `application_name` to my postgres server in the uri like

```
postgres://username:password@host:port/database?application_name=name
```

My question is how I can *force* every incoming connection request to supply this parameter? For logging reasons I don't want to allow connections without this name.

Is that possible?

Comment: Not without hacking the server, I think.

Comment: *Obviously I got administrator access to the server. Sorry if that wasn't clear. Or do you mean this isn't possible with the normal configuration options?

Comment: I mean, change the PostgreSQL server code.

Comment: oh ok thx :-) maybe one day this is possible, I'll leave the question open.